# installing gnuradio 3.8 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

I am installing gnuradio 3.8 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Here is the procedure I used to install gnuradio 3.8:

$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-apt 
$ sudo -H pip install PyBOMBS 
$ mkdir pybombs && cd pybombs 
$ pybombs auto-config 
$ pybombs recipes add gr-recipes git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes.git 
$ pybombs recipes add gr-etcetera git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-etcetera.git 
$ pybombs prefix init ~/pybombs/prefix 
$ source ~/pybombs/prefix/setup_env.sh 
$ pybombs install uhd 
$ sudo apt install git cmake g++ libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev swig python3-numpy python3-mako python3-sphinx python3-lxml doxygen libfftw3-dev libcomedi-dev libsdl1.2-dev libgsl-dev libqwt-qt5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev python3-pyqt5 liblog4cpp5-dev libzmq3-dev python3-yaml python3-click python3-click-plugins 
$ pybombs install gnuradio38

I got the dependency list from here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuInstall

after gnuradio installed, I had to update ~/pybombs/prefix/setup_env.sh and changed python2.6 to python3.6 and changed python2.7 to python3 (as stated here https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio#pybombs-with-support-of-python-3x)

Is that all the changes?  Did I miss any steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention the other steps of https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio#pybombs-with-support-of-python-3x:

- Change the PYTHONPATH line in setup_env.sh, to just 3.x paths.
- Find the PyBOMBS recipe "gnuradio.lwr" in .pybombs directory, check this for reference `https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes/blob/master/gnuradio.lwr`
- Change the "gitbranch" to "master".
- In gnuradio.lwr recipe file, add "-DENABLE_CTRLPORT_THRIFT=OFF" in "config_opt".

Comment: There is a gnuradio38.lwr recipe and gitbranch needs to be set to maint-3.8. https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes/pull/155